# Enabling Attachments

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice if there is an option to attach files. Currently user needs to upload the file into a file hosting sites and then place links to those. Over time these links will get broken and lose the context.

Comment: I disagree. Users need to get better at asking more concise questions that isolate their specific issue, rather than posting an entire code file and saying, "This doesn't work".

Comment: Case in point: Here is a user who essentially has an issue with a jQuery selector (one line of code), but posts his entire solution: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121969/jquery-selector-wont-work-sp2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been requested several times but never implemented on StackExchange.

- [Please add a system to allow file uploads attached to questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/please-add-a-system-to-allow-file-uploads-attached-to-questions-and-answers)
- [feature request: upload solution files](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58528/feature-request-upload-solution-files)
- [Where to upload too big files?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172046/where-to-upload-too-big-files)
- [How to upload files/images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228467/uploading-files-images-into-stack-overflow)

This has been the general rule for at [least five years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4643/180230):

> There are lots of free file hosts you can use -- it puts us in a difficult position to be hosting arbitrary files for user.

You could try to ask on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ but don't expect a warm welcome ;-)